# How to populate xUnit [Theory] and [InlineData] with values from a method

Tags: c#, xunit

Is there a way to input data into `[InlineData]` values for xUnit tests? I can't seem to do so as it requires constants.

Comment: `[ClassData]` or `[MemberData]`?

Comment: [xUnit Theory: Working With InlineData, MemberData, ClassData](https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/)

Answer (score 4):

For calling Methods as data you have to use `[MemberData]` rather than `[InlineData]`. In MemberData you can specify a function via `nameof`, which returns the expected parameters as result.

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetNumbers()
    {
        yield return new object[] { 5, 1, 3, 9 };
        yield return new object[] { 7, 1, 5, 3 };
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(GetNumbers))]
    public void AllNumbers_AreOdd_WithMemberData(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(a));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(b));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(c));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(d));
    }
```

I am not sure but if I remeber correctly, the function you call, needs to return `IEnumerable<object[]>`, which XUnit will sort out into the parameters of the test, and you have to use `yield return` if you want multiple datasets to be used.